# How to get rid of Java EE application client by using another technology?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

I have Java EE application client which accesses remote EJBs. The reason for its existence is because we have some legacy system which requires a permanent TCP connection opened, and this is against Java EE specs to do in an Java EE container (or at least, it requires an RA which is a major PITA to implement).

Is there some other way to re-architecture JBoss EAR application so that:

- permanent connection to the remote server can be maintained, while still interacting with EJBs in EAR
- somehow get rid of application client, because it is needlessly wasting a lot of memory (since it runs a minimal version of server just to do some simple tasks).

Application server is JBoss7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a permanent TCP/IP connection really necessary? If not, then JMS and SOAP can send byte messages between a client of any language and your session bean.

#### SOAP

Annotate the session bean with `@WebService`and implementing a SOAP interface that works like a facade to the bean. Actually I'd like to decouple the views of your business logic right from the start and write another session bean to be a SOAP web service and then let him use the other bean you're trying to provide an adapter for.

#### JMS

If the communication into and out from your enterprise javabean is not too complex, then consider writing a JMS message driven bean and let him serve as a facade to the bean you're trying to expose. There is a splendid hands-on example of the "message facade" approach in the book [Java Message Service](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522045) that begins on page 171.

#### UMS?

Message queue 4.3 (The JMS provider in GlassFish) introduced [Universal Message Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6360/ghlir/index.html) that might of interest to you. UMS bridge JMS to any kind of http-enabled device.

Good luck and let us know how everything turned out for you!